# curl still emitting progress info even with --silent option

Tags: bash, osx, curl, stderr

I have this curl command:

```
  curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/run-tsc-if/master/install.sh | bash || {
   echo "Could not install run-tsc-if on your system.";
   exit 1;
  }
```

and it still writes out progress info as stderr:

```
ntrs update routine stderr:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
ntrs update routine stderr:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   876  100   876    0     0   2304      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2305
```

it's still writing progress info as stderr. I am on MacOS. Anyone know why  curl is misbehaving?

Answer (score 4):

The script that you fetch using `curl --silent` and then execute with `bash` contains a call to `curl` *without* the `--silent` option, which is why you're seeing the progress indicator.

The relevant part of the remote script:

```bash
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/run-tsc-if/master/run.sh?$(date +%s)" \
--output "$HOME/.oresoftware/bash/run-tsc-if.sh"
```

Before running random scripts from internet, always have a look at them to see what they are doing.